# Where can I find the change log for Android 4.0.4?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm curious what changed in Android 4.0.4. Is there an official change log somewhere? It seems very well hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a maintenance update for bug fixes. This is the best I can find:

> Revision 3 (March 2012)
>
> Maintenance update. The system version is **4.0.4.**
>
> Note: This system image includes support for emulator hardware
>   graphics acceleration when used with SDK Tools r17 or higher. (more
>   info)

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.3.html

[Unofficial change log](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1481044)

[Revision change log](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1SQOarUeVBiqEpJwst8l1eboZTXIxXgvHvfLajMz_P5E) and [more details](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1Jx3-OX58QXR3tN-OQF55nRyR2zhIUIx_D7iexca_XUk)

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Ice_Cream_Sandwich_4.0.x)

- Stability improvements
- Better camera performance
- Smoother screen rotation
- Improved phone number recognition